# How to remove auto generated comments in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I made a jsp file in a netbeans project. Netbeans automatically adds a comment which contains author, time and project name. I do NOT want this information to be added. I tried to remove this via Netbeans > Tools > Templates > Web > JSP >  Settings > User.properties file is now opened > Uncomment the user param in the user.poperties and set user = . This does not help. How do I remove the auto generated comments ?

```
<%-- 
    Document   : bbc
    Created on : acb
    Author     : james
--%>
```

User.properties:

```
#
# Here, or in other properties files in this directory, you can define
# various properties that you want to make available to the template
# processor while creating various templates.
#

# uncomment the next line and specify your user name to be used in new templates
user =
```

I set user = nothing. How do I remove the date and file name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to : <kbd>Tools > Templates > Web > JSP > open in editor</kbd> . Do not open the <kbd>settings</kbd> button for this.

remove :

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ${abc}
    Created on : ${abc}
    Author     : ${abc}
--%>
```

Comment: When I remove and save my jsp template, It shows me a warning `the  ${encoding} character set that is used in JSP.jsp is not a valid character set for JSP pages. Do you want to save the file using UTF-8 character set ?` I wonder why this error happened only afer removing the comment generator code. Saying yes anyway.